# Tmp folder and read-only-system...file system corrupt

Tags: filesystems

fron 1 month I have always problems with my VPS. Before it was file system, it told **Can't create/write to file '/tmp/** - error 30.

My host had fixed the problem but today tried to upgraded Webmin and now doesn't work more:

> Installing package(s) with command apt-get -y install libmount1..
>
> Reading package lists... Building dependency tree... Reading state
>
> information... The following packages were automatically installed and
>
> are no longer required:   linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic
>
> linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic   linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic
>
> linux-image-3.13.0-41-generic   linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic
>
> linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic   linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic
>
> linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic   linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic
>
> linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic   linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic
>
> linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic   linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic
>
> linux-image-3.13.0-54-generic   linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic
>
> linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic   linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic
>
> linux-image-3.13.0-59-generic   linux-image-3.13.0-61-generic Use
>
> 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them. The following packages will be
>
> upgraded:   libmount1 1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5
>
> not upgraded. Need to get 60.2 kB of archives. After this operation, 0
>
> B of additional disk space will be used. Get:1
>
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libmount1 amd64
>
> 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7 [60.2 kB] Fetched 60.2 kB in 0s (742 kB/s) (Reading database ... 54924 files and directories currently
>
> installed.) Preparing to unpack
>
> .../libmount1_2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
>
> libmount1:amd64 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7) over (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6) ...
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg exited unexpectedly E: Failed to write
>
> temporary StateFile /var/lib/apt/extended_states.tmp .. install
>
> failed!
>
> Now updating libuuid1 .. Installing package(s) with command apt-get -y
>
> install libuuid1 .. dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area:
> Read-only file system

**I tried to restart MySQL** but now also MySQL is dead and I can't do backup of my database...

I can still connect via SSH and FTP to server.

Just I connect to SSH I have various errors:

> [163488.687353] EXT4-fs error (device xvda1):
> ext4_mb_generate_buddy:756: group
> 318, 23274 clusters in bitmap, 23231 in gd; block bitmap corrupt.
> [163488.687368] Aborting journal on device xvda1-8. [163488.687583]
> EXT4-fs (xvda1): Remounting filesystem read-only [163488.687725] BUG:
> unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000
> 000000028 [163488.687732] IP: []
> __ext4_error_inode+0x31/0x160 [163488.687738] PGD 6cffc067 PUD 530dc067 PMD 0 [163488.687743] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP [163488.687747]
> Modules linked in: xt_multiport ip6t_REJECT xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_con
> ntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 ipt_REJECT xt_limit xt_tcpudp xt_addrtype
> nf_conntrac                                              k_ipv4
> nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables
> nf_conntrack_netbi                                              os_ns
> nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack
> ipt                                              able_filter ip_tables
> x_tables crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel
> aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd
> [163488.687780] CPU: 0 PID: 14460 Comm: dpkg Tainted: G        W
> 3.13.0-24-ge                                              neric #47-Ubuntu [163488.687785] task: ffff880053005fc0 ti: ffff880038aa2000 task.ti: ffff880038a
> a2000 [163488.687789] RIP: e030:[]
> [] __ext4_erro
> r_inode+0x31/0x160 [163488.687795] RSP: e02b:ffff880038aa3a98  EFLAGS:
> 00010292 [163488.687799] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000
> RCX: 00000000009f000                                              0
> [163488.687805] RDX: 00000000000012ea RSI: ffffffff81a6ae62 RDI:
> 000000000000000                                              0
> [163488.687810] RBP: ffff880038aa3b28 R08: ffffffff81a74b60 R09:
> 000000000000000                                              5
> [163488.687814] R10: 00000000ffffffe2 R11: ffff880038aa380e R12:
> 00000000009f000                                              0
> [163488.687818] R13: ffffffff81835240 R14: 00000000000012ea R15:
> ffffffff81a74b6                                              0
> [163488.687827] FS:  00007f2491816840(0000) GS:ffff88007d200000(0000)
> knlGS:0000                                              000000000000
> [163488.687832] CS:  e033 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
> [163488.687835] CR2: 0000000000000028 CR3: 000000007add2000 CR4:
> 000000000000266                                              0
> [163488.687840] Stack: [163488.687842]  ffff880038aa3aa0
> 0000000000000103 d26d9f89685cebc7 000000000000
> 0007 [163488.687848]  0000000000000006 0000000000000000
> 0000000000000138 ffff88007b9d
> a2a0 [163488.687855]  ffff880038aa3b28 ffffffff812689c2
> ffffffff810676cf ffff8800384b
> d680 [163488.687862] Call Trace: [163488.687866]  []
> ? ext4_journal_abort_handle+0x42/0xc0 [163488.687871]
> [] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x8f/0xa0 [163488.687875]
> [] __ext4_handle_dirty_metadata+0x10f/0x1c0
> [163488.687880]  [] ext4_free_blocks+0x646/0xbf0
> [163488.687885]  [] ?
> radix_tree_lookup_slot+0xe/0x10 [163488.687890]  []
> ext4_clear_blocks+0x189/0x290 [163488.687895]  []
> ext4_free_data+0x143/0x190 [163488.687900]  []
> ext4_ind_truncate+0x1bd/0x490 [163488.687904]  [] ?
> ext4_discard_preallocations+0x159/0x460 [163488.687909]
> [] ? mutex_lock+0x12/0x2f [163488.687914]
> [] ? ext4_orphan_add+0x5c/0x1d0 [163488.687919]
> [] ? __ext4_journal_start_sb+0x69/0xe0
> [163488.687924]  [] ext4_truncate+0x30c/0x3c0
> [163488.687929]  [] ext4_evict_inode+0x491/0x4f0
> [163488.687933]  [] evict+0xb0/0x1b0 [163488.687937]
> [] iput+0xf5/0x180 [163488.687942]
> [] do_unlinkat+0x18e/0x2b0 [163488.687946]
> [] ? context_tracking_user_exit+0x4f/0xc0
> [163488.687951]  [] ?
> syscall_trace_enter+0x145/0x250 [163488.687956]  []
> SyS_unlink+0x16/0x20 [163488.687961]  []
> tracesys+0xe1/0xe6 [163488.687965] Code: 48 89 e5 41 57 4d 89 c7 41 56
> 41 89 d6 41 55 49 89 f5 48 c
> 7 c6 62 ae a6 81 41 54 49 89 cc 53 48 89 fb 48 83 ec 68 4c 89 4c 24 60
> <48> 8b 4                                              7 28 48 8b 57
> 40 48 8b 80 f8 02 00 00 48 8b 40 68 89 90 [163488.688008] RIP
> [] __ext4_error_inode+0x31/0x160 [163488.688014]
> RSP  [163488.688017] CR2: 0000000000000028
> [163488.688049] ---[ end trace d26d9f89685cebc8 ]--- [163898.263253]
> init: mysql main process (31940) killed by KILL signal [163898.416951]
> type=1400 audit(1442421984.518:18): apparmor="STATUS" operation=
> "profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
> pid=14863 comm="a
> pparmor_parser" [163898.532076] init: mysql main process (14875)
> terminated with status 1 [163898.532107] init: mysql main process
> ended, respawning [163899.521793] init: mysql post-start process
> (14876) terminated with status 1 [163899.549762] type=1400
> audit(1442421985.650:19): apparmor="STATUS" operation=
> "profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
> pid=14899 comm="a
> pparmor_parser" [163899.605335] init: mysql main process (14911)
> terminated with status 1 [163899.605379] init: mysql main process
> ended, respawning [163900.616355] init: mysql post-start process
> (14912) terminated with status 1 [163900.635946] type=1400
> audit(1442421986.734:20): apparmor="STATUS" operation=
> "profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
> pid=14935 comm="a
> pparmor_parser" [163900.698158] init: mysql main process (14947)
> terminated with status 1 [163900.698200] init: mysql respawning too
> fast, stopped [163912.524831] init: Failed to write to log file
> /var/log/upstart/systemd-login
> d.log [164061.712485] type=1400 audit(1442422147.814:21):
> apparmor="STATUS" operation=
> "profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
> pid=15030 comm="a
> pparmor_parser" [164061.767517] init: mysql main process (15042)
> terminated with status 1 [164061.767551] init: mysql main process
> ended, respawning [164062.776180] init: mysql post-start process
> (15043) terminated with status 1 [164062.802000] type=1400
> audit(1442422148.902:22): apparmor="STATUS" operation=
> "profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
> pid=15066 comm="a
> pparmor_parser" [164062.859336] init: mysql main process (15078)
> terminated with status 1 [164062.859369] init: mysql main process
> ended, respawning [164063.868893] init: mysql post-start process
> (15079) terminated with status 1 [164063.891965] type=1400
> audit(1442422149.990:23): apparmor="STATUS" operation=
> "profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
> pid=15102 comm="a
> pparmor_parser" [164063.947418] init: mysql main process (15114)
> terminated with status 1 [164063.947449] init: mysql respawning too
> fast, stopped [164077.650423] type=1400 audit(1442422163.750:24):
> apparmor="STATUS" operation=
> "profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
> pid=15150 comm="a
> pparmor_parser" [164077.705842] init: mysql main process (15162)
> terminated with status 1 [164077.705873] init: mysql main process
> ended, respawning [164078.714713] init: mysql post-start process
> (15163) terminated with status 1 [164078.734022] type=1400
> audit(1442422164.834:25): apparmor="STATUS" operation=
> "profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
> pid=15186 comm="a
> pparmor_parser" [164078.792127] init: mysql main process (15198)
> terminated with status 1 [164078.792157] init: mysql main process
> ended, respawning [164079.801544] init: mysql post-start process
> (15199) terminated with status 1 [164079.822027] type=1400
> audit(1442422165.922:26): apparmor="STATUS" operation=
> "profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
> pid=15222 comm="a
> pparmor_parser" [164079.878910] init: mysql main process (15234)
> terminated with status 1 [164079.878941] init: mysql respawning too
> fast, stopped [164100.211709] type=1400 audit(1442422186.310:27):
> apparmor="STATUS" operation=
> "profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
> pid=15270 comm="a
> pparmor_parser" [164100.273478] init: mysql main process (15282)
> terminated with status 1 [164100.273519] init: mysql main process
> ended, respawning [164101.278431] init: mysql post-start process
> (15283) terminated with status 1 [164101.299116] type=1400
> audit(1442422187.398:28): apparmor="STATUS" operation=
> "profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
> pid=15306 comm="a
> pparmor_parser" [164101.355867] init: mysql main process (15318)
> terminated with status 1 [164101.355911] init: mysql main process
> ended, respawning [164102.362783] init: mysql post-start process
> (15319) terminated with status 1 [164102.388224] type=1400
> audit(1442422188.490:29): apparmor="STATUS" operation=
> "profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
> pid=15342 comm="a
> pparmor_parser" [164102.451563] init: mysql main process (15354)
> terminated with status 1 [164102.451625] init: mysql respawning too
> fast, stopped

How can at least I backup my database?? :( So I'll can reinstall all VPS.

I tried with:
mysqldump -p -u userdb namedb > dbname.sql
-bash: dbname.sql: Read-only file system

But nothing, server is in read-only mode now..I can't do something..

SQL Error:
2002 - No such file or directory

Query:
[READ] Unable to connect to MySQL server

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your post, it's currently un-readable..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dump sql to take backups, you can copy the MySQL data dir, which is usually:

```
/var/lib/mysql
```

Just use SCP to copy it over to your PC. But, if the underlying fs is corrupted at places where those files are written to, unfortunately there's not much you can do. You could netcat the whole partition, and try to analyse it offline and recover data from it. You'll need another machine with public IP for that. Run the following command on that other machine:

```
newvps# nc -l -p 12345 | dd of=/home/xvda1
```

And on your corrupted VPS run:

```
oldvps# dd if=/dev/xvda1 | nc <plubic_ip_ofnewvps> 12345
```

Afterwards you can try to mount that file and pull out data from it...

Either way, I know it's too late, but you should have made regular backups and would avoid all this trouble. Good luck.